I have a blazor server side app with windows auth. Is it possible to force the standard browser login page of the browser each time user enters page?
I have a blazor server side app (.NET7) with windows authentication. So when a user enters the page the first time the standard login dialog of the browser appears. But the next time it is not asked anymore because of the caching of the browser i think.
Is it possible to force the standard login page of the browser each time user enters page? (I know that this is not so userfriendly but I need that beacause of some security requirements of the company). Of course I want to do that programatically in my app, without the user makes any changes in his browser settings.
Is that possible for firefox and edge browsers?
I have tried to add following code to my startup.cs but didn't work
        //*** Prevent browser caching
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            context.Response.OnStarting(state =>
            {
                var httpContext = (HttpContext)state;
                httpContext.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-store";
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }, context);

            await next.Invoke();
        });
        //***

